# PHP PDO STMT Fetch - specify table in $row variable?

Tags: php, pdo, database-connection

I'm using PDO's fetch to return data from two tables (orders and order_items).

The issue is I would like all the order_item row data to be nested as arrays inside each order data row.

Whilst looping through the rows is it possible to do the following?

```
$variable = $row[tablename.columnname]
```

I've tried this with and without specifying an alias for in my query `(SELECT * FROM orders as orders WHERE ...etc..)` and I'm getting an `'Notice: Undefined index:'` error. Any ideas?

EDIT - THIS QUESTION IS DIFFERENT

Comment: How about trying it out? ;-)

Comment: no, they will come back with just the column names. if you want it to come back that way then you need to alias each of the column names.

Comment: once its fetched, it will overwrite that column if there's collision. thats why you alias your columns

Comment: I've tried this with and without specifying an alias for in my query (SELECT * FROM orders as orders WHERE ...etc..) and I'm getting an 'Notice: Undefined index:' error. Any ideas?